# Rule based link processing

Tags: python

Here is piece of code with few if ... else, I appreciate if anyone can clean it.

```
def process_link(post_script_link_list,read_str):
    links_list1 = ['Wq','Ws','Wi','Wd']
    bad_list = ['How long','how long','How much','how much']
    links_list2 = ['Qd']
    result = ''
    for item in bad_list:
        if item in read_str:
            return
    sent_split = read_str.split()
    for linking in post_script_link_list:
        sub_link = re.search('\((.*?)\)',linking).group(1)
        if sub_link in links_list1:         
            if ('Who').lower() in sent_split or 'Who' in sent_split:
                result = 'person'
                break
            elif (('Where').lower() in sent_split or 'Where' in sent_split) and 'What' not in read_str and 'what' not in read_str:
                result = 'location'
                break
            elif ('Why').lower() in sent_split or 'Why' in sent_split:
                result = 'reason'
                break
            elif ('How many').lower() in read_str or 'How many' in read_str:
                result = 'count'
                break
            elif (('When').lower() in sent_split or 'When' in sent_split) and 'What' not in read_str and 'what' not in read_str:
                result = 'time'
                break
            elif (('How').lower() in sent_split or 'How' in sent_split) and ('How long').lower() not in read_str and 'How long' not in read_str and ('How much').lower() not in read_str and 'How much' not in read_str:
                result = 'manner'
                break
        elif sub_link in links_list2:
            check_yn = verify_yesno(post_script_link_list)
            if check_yn == 1:
                result = 'Yes/No'
                break
            elif check_yn == 0:
                result = 'noresult'
                break
            break
        else:
            result = 'noresult'
    return result
```

Comment: Could you provide some background about what you intend to use this code for?

Comment: I have couple of links as given in `links_list1`, along with that, as per 'what,where,when ..' present in query, I am deciding the result

Comment: Could you give example input to the function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For lines like

```
if ('Who').lower() in sent_split or 'Who' in sent_split:
```

you have some extra brackets and can do some manual constant folding, to get

```
if 'who' in sent_split or 'Who' in sent_split:
```

Perhaps you meant

```
if 'who' in read_str.lower().split():
```

?

Assuming so, this would simplify the main part to

```
if  'who' in read_str.lower().split()::
    result = 'person'
    break
elif 'where' in read_str.lower().split(): and 'what' not in read_str.lower():
    result = 'location'
    break
elif 'why' in read_str.lower().split()::
    result = 'reason'
    break
elif 'how many' in read_str.lower():
    result = 'count'
    break
elif 'when' in read_str.lower().split(): and 'what' not in read_str.lower():
    result = 'time'
    break
elif 'how' in read_str.lower().split(): and 'how long' not in read_str.lower() and 'how much' not in read_str.lower():
    result = 'manner'
    break
```

This can be encoded in a data structure:

```
# Give this a better name
def process(read):
    in_notin_result = (
        ('who',      [],       'person'),
        ('where',    ['what'], 'location'),
        ('why',      [],       'reason'),
        ('how many', [],       'count'),
        ('when',     ['what'], 'time'),
        ('how',      ['how long', 'how much'], 'manner'),
    )

    words = read.split()

    for in_sent, notin_read, result in in_notin_result:
        if in_sent in words and all(disallowed not in read for disallowed in notin_read):
            return result

    return None
```

This says that each `if` is of the form

```
word which must be in read.split()
some words (0, 1 or 2) which must not be in read
a result value
```

We put that in the data structure and loop over it:

```
for in_sent, notin_read, result in in_notin_result
```

We check the `in_sent in words` and that `disallowed not in read` for every `disallowed` in the words which must not be in `read`. If this matches, we return `result`, otherwise we go to the next iteration of the loop.

This can be simplified:

```
elif sub_link in links_list2:
    check_yn = verify_yesno(post_script_link_list)
    if check_yn == 1:
        result = 'Yes/No'
        break
    elif check_yn == 0:
        result = 'noresult'
        break
    break
```

to

```
elif sub_link in links_list2:
    check_yn = verify_yesno(post_script_link_list)
    result = 'Yes/No' if check_yn else 'noresult'
    break
```

Note further that

```
('How long').lower() not in read_str and 'How long' not in read_str and ('How much').lower() not in read_str and 'How much' not in read_str:
```

will always be True because of the first filter agains `bad_strings`.

I would short-circuit the `return` instead of `break`ing. It seems to me that you want to return `noresult` on no result, but you default to `''`. If you just default to `'noresult` this would be easier.

```
for linking in post_script_link_list:
    sub_link = re.search('\((.*?)\)', linking).group(1)

    if sub_link in ['Wq','Ws','Wi','Wd']:
        process_result = process(read_str)
        if process_result is not None:
            return process_result

    elif sub_link in ['Qd']:
        return 'Yes/No' if verify_yesno(post_script_link_list) else 'noresult'

return 'noresult'
```

but if you do really want to distinguish these cases you'll need to use your original variant:

```
result = ''
for linking in post_script_link_list:
    ...

    else:
        result = 'noresult'

return result
```

It's not clear because I don't know what the code is meant to do.

This is what I've ended with. I don't know if it works:

```
# Give this a better name
def process(read):
    in_notin_result = (
        ('who',      [],       'person'),
        ('where',    ['what'], 'location'),
        ('why',      [],       'reason'),
        ('how many', [],       'count'),
        ('when',     ['what'], 'time'),
        ('how',      [],       'manner'),
    )
    words = read.split()
    for in_sent, notin_read, result in in_notin_result:
        if in_sent in words and all(disallowed not in read for disallowed in notin_read):
            return result
    return None

def process_link(post_script_link_list, read_str):
    read_str = read_str.lower()

    for item in ('how long', 'how much'):
        if item in read_str:
            return

    for linking in post_script_link_list:
        sub_link = re.search('\((.*?)\)', linking).group(1)

        if sub_link in ['Wq','Ws','Wi','Wd']:
            process_result = process(read_str)
            if process_result is not None:
                return process_result

        elif sub_link in ['Qd']:
            return 'Yes/No' if verify_yesno(post_script_link_list) else 'noresult'

    return 'noresult'
```

Comment: thanks a ton, I dont have points to upvote  : ). Can you please explain `process()` function with some comments, also DS in it

Comment: @user3449212 What does "also DS in it" mean? I've added some clarification.

Comment: `in_notin_result` data structure (DS), and for loop below that in process() function